# "i" not available in current context

Tags: c++, debugging, gcc, gdb, codeblocks

I am trying a debugging tool for the first time and I came up to the following problem:

When I go step by step through the code with a debugger, and when I step into function `ComputeInterest()` and put watch on `i` (mark `i` and right click on it), watch informs me that

> 'i' is not available in current context

I'm also curious why watch didn't already put `i` into local variables. This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

double computeInterest (double base_val, double rate, int years)
{
     double final_multiplier;
     for ( int i = 0; i < years; i++ )
     {
          final_multiplier *= (1 + rate);
     }
     return base_val * final_multiplier;
}

int main ()
{
     double base_val;
     double rate;
     int years;
     cout << "Enter a base value: ";
     cin >> base_val;
     cout << "Enter an interest rate: ";
     cin >> rate;
     cout << "Enter the number of years to compound: ";
     cin >> years;
     cout << "After " << years << " you will have " << computeInterest( base_val, rate, years ) << " money" << endl;
}
```

I'm using the latest version 13.12 of Code:Blocks, g++ (GCC) 4.8.1 and GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.1.

Comment: Have you tried to declare `i` outside the `for` statement?

Comment: i only exists inside that loop

Comment: Step inside the `for` loop and see if it shows up then. `i`'s scope is only within the `for` itself.

Comment: Entirely likely that by the time you look `i` no longer exists.  Even if you put `i` outside the loop, the compiler may (should if not a debug build) take note that `i` is not being used anymore and get rid of it. Since this is a pretty simple loop, `i` might only exist in a register and be totally lost as soon as it's not needed.

Comment: Btw your problem is that you forgot to initialize `final_multiplier`. If you had enabled a sufficiently high warning level, your compiler would have [told you](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/759e9a2934d1adab) and saved you four days of work.

Comment: You and your x-y problem-solving mentality, @BaummitAugen

Comment: @user4581301 I will never pass on an opportunity to promote compiler warnings. :)

Comment: @BaummitAugen well, this is an exercise for debugging in book (this is the exact code), watch should inform me that I have non-initialized value, I guess? Sorry for not mentioning in question :)

Comment: As of declaring 'i', I already tried doing that inside for loop, but it still shows me that it is not available. :(

Comment: Pretty much what @BaummitAugen said: read the compiler warnings. If they aren't turned on, turn them on. This may be overkill for most cases, but  adding -`pedantic -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra -Werror` to a g++ compiler command makes it hard to ignore. `-Werror` fails the build if there are any warnings, `-pedantic` is anally retentive,  and `-pedantic-errors` makes that anal retention fatal. If there is anything the compiler can detect as odd in the code, you have to justify it or the program will not compile.

Comment: @GreatDuke I guess a watchpoint on `final_multiplier` would have stopped in your loop for the first time where it already is read. You could have noticed that. But in this case, even compiler warnings solve your problem in seconds, and for more complex cases of uninitialized reads, valgrind is a very good tool. I feel like gdb is just the wrong tool for this kind of bug, which is why you wasted four days of your precious time. ;)

Comment: My question is why inside local variable watch there is no 'i' declared? I have final_multiplier declared, but no 'i', and when I try to do it does not allow me manually to do it. Am I missing something in this comments? :(

Comment: @GreatDuke I don't think so, since comments are not meant to be answers. Wait until someone who knows the solution (unlike me, since I do not use codeblocks) comes along and posts an answer as an answer, i.e. down there: vvvvvvvvvvv

Comment: I think @crashmstr is right... try int i;  for (i = 0; i < years; i++)... You should see that i is in your scope then

Comment: `i` is just a loop counter. There are no pointer or anything fancy. Odds are really good that `i` only exists in a hardware register and the moment it's not being used anymore, it's gone. The debugger might not even be able to see it, but it should.

Comment: Oddly enough, I can't get a warning for uninitialized doubles even with `-Wuninitialized`, but I do for ints. No idea why.

Answer (score 4):

`i` is defined and exists only inside that scope (the for loop):

```
 for ( int i = 0; i < years; i++ )
 {
      final_multiplier *= (1 + rate);
 }
```

So once you step into one of these lines you will be able to inspect 'i'. And once you are out of this loop, `i` will be unavailable again.

**EDIT:**

Make sure that you build with no optimization (-O0) and with debug information (-g) compilation flags.

**EDIT2:**

It also might be the GDB issue. Because I also worked with GDB v7.5.1, if I remember correctly, and had the same behavior. Maybe on a higher version of GDB you will get the expected behavior. As [Baum mit Augen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3002139/baum-mit-augen) mentioned in the comments below, GDB v7.9 behaves as you expect.

Comment: Actually, you can add a watchpoint on `i` from anywhere in the function. The loop-scope should not be an issue.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I am not sure about it. Maybe it depends on the compiler version and the debugger. Because I also had such debugging behaviors and usually the debugger was able to detect the watched variables once one steps into the relevant scope.

Comment: I just tried it successfully with gdb 7.9, but I would guess that 7.6 should be good enough too.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Maybe it is the GDB issue. Because I think I worked with GDB 7.5.1 (if I remember correctly) and had the described by OP behavior too.

Comment: MinGW port of GDB 7.6 fails to spot `i`.

Comment: @user4581301 Can I overcome somehow that problem, I ticked out any possible optimizations and tried to watch inside for loop? Should I install newer version of GDB? If so, please tell me how, I'm using Windows' mingw version of gnu debugger, and it doesn't seem to me that I can find newer than 7.6.1 gdb(correct me if I'm wrong please)?

Comment: @GreatDuke For now, just write it off as a bug in the tools and declare `i` ahead of the for loop. `int i; <newline> for (i = 0; i < years; i++)`. That makes it visible to me at any rate. You should lose nothing in terms of performance. With Mingw you can try some of the experimental builds, but if you're learning, you don't want to add dealing with bugs in the toolchain to your workload. Hell, if you are a long-time pro you don't want to risk tool bugs without a damn good reason. Alternative are try [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com) which may be more up to date. or dive into Unix.